# Polynomial sum help

Tags: polynomials

Let $p(x)=x^6-x^5-x^3-x^2-x$. Furthermore, let $a, b, c, d$ be the roots of the $x^4-x^3-x^2-x$ polynomial.

What is the value of $p(a)+p(b)+p(c)+p(d)$?

Should I use Newton-Girard Formulas?

It is a homework for me.

Comment: For a root $p(a)=0$, does it not?

Comment: @zoli aha that's what I thought as well, but $a,b,c,d$ are roots of a different polynomial.

Comment: Oh, yahh. Sorry.

Comment: let $q(x)$ be the other polynomial. Since $q(0) = 0$, one of the root is zero, say $d = 0$.Since $p(x) - (x^2+1)q(x) = x^3$, $p(a)+p(b)+p(c)+p(d) = a^3+b^3+c^3$. Now apply Netwon's identities to the cubic polynomial $q(x)/x$.

Answer (score 1):

As $x^4-x^3-x^2-x=x(x^3-x^2-x-1)$

WLOG $d=0\implies p(d)=?$

So, $a,b,c$ are the roots of  $$x^3-x^2-x-1=0$$

$\implies a+b+c=1,ab+bc+ca=-1,abc=1\ \ \  \ (1)$

$$x^6-x^5-x^3-x^2-x=x^3(x^3-x^2-x-1)+x^4-x^2-x$$

$$=x^3(x^3-x^2-x-1)+x(x^3-x^2-x-1)+(x^3-x^2-x-1)+x^2+x+1$$

$p(a)=a^2+a+1$  etc.

$p(a)+p(b)+(c)=1+1+1+(a+b+c)+(a+b+c)^2-2(ab+bc+ca)$

Use $(1)$